# cannot convert from int[][] to int**?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code in the caller function

```
int matrix[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3},{4, 5, 6},{7, 8, 9}};
find_index(matrix);
```

and the find_index's prototype is:

```
void find_index(int** m);
```

and I got compiler error:  cannot convert 'int (* )[3]' to ‘int**’

Anyway I can fix this? Thanks!

update:

is there a way that I can then use m[a][b] operator in the second function instead of passing the column number and do m[a * col_num + b]?

Comment: where in `matrix` is an array of pointers? Of course they are not compatible types...

Comment: @tenfour the confusion obviously comes from the fact that you can pass an `int[]` to a function expecting an `int*`, but not an `int[][]` to a function expecting an `int**`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A double indexed array still just corresponds to a single pointer, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: is there a way that I can then use m[a][b] operator in the second function instead of passing the column number and do m[a * col_num + b]? Thanks!

Comment: if you really want to use m[a][b] inside the function, you can declare it as find_index(int m[][3])

Comment: you definitely don't need to pass column number.  if you pass the array as int*, then you just need to understand how the columns/rows are laid out linearly.  so if you pass an int* m, you would find m[0] = 1, m[3] = 4, m[6] = 7, etc.  The memory is laid out linearly with each row following the previous

Answer (score 4):

In memory, an `int**` looks like

```
[0] ----> [0] ---> int
          [1] ---> int
          [2] ---> int

[1] ----> [0] ---> int
          [1] ---> int
          [2] ---> int

[2] ----> [0] ---> int
          [1] ---> int
          [2] ---> int
```

But an `int[][]` looks like

```
[0][1][2][0][1][2][0][1][2]
(0)      (1)      (2)
```

So you can see how indexing them would cause different things to happen (one dereferences pointers, one performs the arithmetic differently), and they are not compatible. Trying to index an `int[][]` like an `int**` would cause one of the integers you are storing to be dereferenced, causing Undefined Behaviour.